# Can Borderlands class mods raise a skill past 5 points?

Tags: borderlands

Basically, can I use a class mod to raise a skill past 5, or is it capped at 5?

For example, if I am playing with Lilith, and I have my Girl Power ability raised up to 4, through leveling, and then I get a class mod that adds +3, is my Girl Power now at 5 or 7?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, it won't show up as 7, but it will work.

This can be verified by using Mordecai's bird of prey skill with his bloodwing and counting the number of hits the bird goes through before returning.

However, keep in mind that boosting any probability above 100% won't matter (like having more than 100% chance of shield penetration on trespass).  The extra damage % will still count.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that in order to benefit from the skill point boost from a mod, *you have to have at least one point in the skill*. If you don't have Girl Power at all, then you will not get any benefit  (unlike say, Diablo II, where you could get "free" access to abilities by equipping items with +X to skills you didn't have).

Comment: That comments explains a lot to me. I've been wondering why some of my MODS seemed to be more effective but were less 'expensive' or at least included less skills - but now I realise they included mods I had skill points in!!! I finally get it.

Answer (score 5):

*What am I seeing here?* I have 2 points in the Safeguard skill which boosts my shield, and 1 point in the Hardened skill which boosts my health. The Centurion COM that I have equipped adds +3 points to Safeguard and +4 points to Hardened, making an even 5/5 for both.
I note my max shield and health before, put one more point in Safeguard and Hardened to push them to 6/5 each, and note my max shield and health after.
Conclusion: If the COM's skill-boosts couldn't push the skills over their natural limit, my max shield and health would not have gone up.

If you conduct the same test that I did, note that sometimes the max shield and health doesn't update in pause, which threw me off for a bit.