# Does Ransack have any benefits beyond 5 skill points?

Tags: borderlands

In Borderlands, there is a skill called Ransack. With a class mod, it's possible to push the effect of this over 5 out of the 5 skill point natural maximum. However, some skills have no extra effect from being pushed over their limit. This skill could have no benefit from overstacking if it's coded to only drop one, or something like 110% could mean one guaranteed item + 10% chance of another. What is it?

Here are two example clips:

While this one does not actually have overstacked Ransack, it can still provide data by showing something other than ammo or money spawning from a Ransack kill:

I am thinking that if someone could mess with their game file to set the Ransack value to a ridiculously high number and see if each Ransack kill causes many items to spawn, the question could be answered rather handily.

Comment: I don't think you can exceed 5 points per skill in Borderlands 1, I believe that was added in Borderlands 2. Lemme look that up ;).

Comment: [It seems you CAN exceed 5 points](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/942812-borderlands/answers?qid=122977), the game just doesn't show it clearly. I never knew...

Comment: It's not just that it seems, but that it is so: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/115788/46216

Comment: It's a matter of speech, look it up if you don't understand. This is turning into a discussion between us, which is not what this site is for, so I'm going to delete my answer and I sincerely hope someone else can satisfy you with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The benefits for every skill in Borderlands *keep scaling in the same degree* with skill points granted by mods, up to 9 points.

For example, with the right combination of points and mod, you can reduce Bloodwing's cooling time to ~3 sec. A mod with +4 `Predator` points and 5 points already spent will result in 9 points granting -27s of cooldown (`5 * 3 + 4 * 3`).

In the case of `Ransack`, since 5 skill points means 100% chance of an extra loot roll, further points are wasted. A mod that includes 4 or 5 points will grant you that 100% as long as you spend one point to activate the skill, leaving 4 points free to learn/upgrade something else.